# Less recursive auto grid

Tags: css, less

Hello i found a piece of code, for recursive auto grid written in .less for which i need clarification. This code is working fine. Mostly i need clarification for `@number-cols` from where i get this variable, when is not stated, rest of code i mostly understand ?

Less

main

```
 .container {

.container-fixed();

[class*='col-'] {

    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}

.make-grid(@container-xs);
.make-grid(@container-sm);
.make-grid(@container-md);
.make-grid(@container-lg);
}
```

mixins

```
.container-fixed(@gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {

 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 padding-left: (@gutter / 2);
 padding-right: (@gutter / 2);
}

 .generate-columns(@container-width; @number-cols; @i: 1) when (@i =< @number-cols) {

 .col-@{i} {

    @single-width: @container-width / @number-cols; 
    width: @i * @single-width;
  }

 .generate-columns(@container-width; @number-cols; @i + 1);
 }

  .make-grid(@container-width) {

  @media(min-width: @container-width) {

  width: calc(@container-width + 5px);

.generate-columns(@container-width, @grid-c);
 }
 }
```

Variables

```
  @grid-c:          12;
  @grid-gutter-width:   30px;

  @container-xs:                ((480px + @grid-gutter-width));
  @container-sm:                ((720px + @grid-gutter-width));
  @container-md:                ((940px + @grid-gutter-width));
  @container-lg:                ((1140px + @grid-gutter-width));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@number-cols` is part of the mixin declaration.

The first time you see `.generate-columns` is the declaration of the mixin.

Then you 'call' the mixin later, within `.make-grid`.

You 'make-grid' with the supplied variables in 'Main' eg; `.make-grid(@container-xs);` and within that call, it calls `.generate-columns` using `@grid-c` as the value.

`@number-cols` is just a param, `@grid-c` is an argument.

Comment: one question, should i keep as it is or i can put @grid-c as i can see i end up with same result or i am wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but you can keep it as is. If you want to generate classes with a different grid, like 16 columns, then you would change it to `@grid-c: 16;`. You would leave `@number-cols` as is @stormfist

Comment: Sorry my question was is that parameter `@number-cols` necessary for some reason, or i can put an argument `@grid-c` instead for easier understanding ?

Comment: I'm not sure if `@grid-c` falls in the scope of the mixin declaration - I would leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing @number-cols with the variable @grid-c instead. Doesn't seem that @number-cols is defined as a variable and @grid-c seems to be the columns variable. Hope this helps you.

Comment: this is a thing i did implement code as it is and its working and i can't figure out that @number-cols from where is taken ...

Comment: no ... compile normal and create CSS with columns as it should ... because that i am puzzled ...

Comment: erm i now placed (@grid-c) instead (@number-cols) and recieved same result ... working as before with (@number-cols) O.o